# Мне нужно записать текст в переменную, а затем через if проверить её содержимое не учитывая регистр. А затем вывести результат.(Python)

Tags: python

Пример —

```
a = input ("Значение переменной?")
if a == "Abc":
    print ("+")
```

Пользователь может ввести "Abc" любыми буквами(заглавными/прописными), и должен вывестись +.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: приведите к нижнему регистру и сравнивайте с нижним регистром

Answer (score 3):

```py
a = input ("Значение переменной?")
a = a.lower()
if a == "abc":
    print ("+")
```